# Write to serial in Java

Tags: java, linux, serial-port, raspbian

I have to send strings to a serial line quite quickly. I'm currently just calling a simple shell script, but I feel like I should be able to do this in Java natively. What is a better/faster/cleaner way to do this? The code is running on a Rpi with raspbian.

Java code:

```
public static synchronized boolean sendString(String s){
    String target = "/home/pi/send.sh " + s;
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try {
        rt.exec(target);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Bash code:

```
echo "$@" > /dev/ttyACM0
```

Comment: Use Pi4J :) I do. Its great :) http://pi4j.com/

Comment: http://pi4j.com/example/serial.html

Comment: I will certainly be checking out pi4j! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can open /dev/ttyACM0 as a file and write to it.  Make sure you have proper access rights to /dev/ttyACM0, maybe install a udev rule to give you proper privileges,